# "Unable to load asset" with image picker

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using [Image Picker package](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) in my **Flutter** project
I choose image from gallery then preview it in `Image.asset` widget

The problem here is if image name *"example_name.png"* (without spaces) the image is visible on the screen, but if image name *"example name.png"* (with spaces) the image is invisible like this [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6rTO.png).

> Error: `Unable to load asset: /storage/emulated/0/Download/images (9).jpeg`

```dart
File _image;


Image.asset(
  _image != null
      ? "${_image.path}"
      : getImage("icon.png"),
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
  width: 120,
  height: 120,
);

...

Future chooseFile() async {    
  await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery).then((image) {    
    setState(() {    
      _image = image;    
    });    
  });    
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are using the wrong `Image` constructor. Use `Image.file` instead of `Image.asset`. `Image.asset` load files packaged in the application (`assets` section of `pubspec.yaml`) and `ImagePicker` does not have access to them.

Comment: what about if need to access to both of them? For example in my app I need to load images and any file separately. Does it mean I need to use both packages?

Answer (score 1):

Using Image.file is a good option but you like to display it in an effective way use
Image.file(_image).image this will help you  to convert Image file to image provider

Answer (score 1):

in the `image_picker` (version 0.6.7 + 22) I was able to recover the image with this condition

```
    if (photo == null) {
        return Image (
          image: AssetImage ('assets / no-image.png'),
          height: 300.0,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        );
      } else {
        return Image.file (
          Photo,
          height: 300.0,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        );
      }
```